# Create hidden user account in Windows and should not show document folder in My Computer

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

How can I create a hidden user account with administrator rights in Windows XP ?

- It should not show in user list at log-on screen.
- Document folder should not show in My Computer.
- User should not show in Control panel - User Accounts.

> Other than the administrator, no one should not find that hidden user

How can I do it ?

Comment: With group policy you can hide the whole control panel, but I don't know about only Users and Groups.  (Of course, you would also need to lock down the use of MMC from the command line so no one adds the user and group snapin.)  I believe hiding the directory can be done with NTFS permissions.  Too bad there isn't a white hat admin rootkit for this. :)

Comment: You can read a similar tutorial here. http://agnipulse.com/2009/07/hiding-a-user-account-in-windows-xp/ You can also mark the Documents folder as hidden to prevent others from seeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2006/09/hide-user-accounts-from-the-windows-xp-welcome-screen/) on IntelliAdmin has a complete walkthrough for hiding a user on the login screen.

You need to create a registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
```

> Under this key you simply create a new DWORD value – the name matches the users name exactly, and the value is one of the following (Decimal format)
>
> 0 – Hides the user just from the welcome screen
>   1 – The user is shown

As this page warns, make sure you leave at least one account visible!

I can confirm that this works under Windows 7 as well.

I'm not sure about the other two requirements though.